# Android signed APK failed to load images

Tags: react-native

I followed [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#content) tutorial and generated signed APK , but when i try to run in my android emulator i got `Unfortunatley AppName stopped`

from adb logcat

`E/AndroidRuntime( 3752): com.facebook.react.modules.core.JavascriptException: Requiring unknown module "AppName/images/home.png", stack:`

but home.png is bundled in apk!

`/AppName/android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-release/res/drawable-mdpi-v4/images_home.png`

Note : My app is working fine in development mode

Comment: That file is in the mdpi (medium density) folder, chances are you have a much higher resolution device and it needs to be in another folder. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: @rooftop first of thanks alot for reply, my emulator is Nexus 5 (Android 5.1) , if it needs to be copied in different folders by react native bundler i must provide high res image ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, you might try (for a test, giving it a @3x extension: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#static-image-resources

Comment: just tried that no luck :( , looks like i am missing something obvious here ..